# How to verify camera calibration was successful by projecting 3D point to 2D image?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I'm following the openCV cookbook for camera calibration, using their [cameraCalibration](http://opencv-cookbook.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Chapter%2009/CameraCalibrator.cpp) and [calibrate](http://opencv-cookbook.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Chapter%2009/calibrate.cpp) functions.

I managed to get my camera intrinsic parameters and distortion coefficients. I'm not exactly sure how you'd go about obtaining the two dimensional points using the 3 dimensional space.

[image]

As far I'm aware, I'm trying to multiply the camera matrix by the 3 dimensional space to get the same original 2d points which I presumed  are `std::vector<cv::Point2f> imageCorners;` for each image, but I'm not sure what would the 3d space be, and I originally  thought I'd multiply each `std::vector<cv::Point3f> objectCorners;` 3d point by the camera intrinsic parameters, but then realized it wouldn't makes sense since it'd be constant for all images. Am I missing something in this picture?

I have 10 images, and I managed to get a hold a camera matrix, and distortion coefficients. I'm not aware on how to get the rotation-translation matrix, nor intrinsic perspective projection

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what your question is. Are you asking what values to use for `X, Y, Z`, or what the resulting `x, y, w` mean, or what the camera matrix means? Note that you haven't included the intrinsic matrix, the rotation-translation matrix that is labeled as `[R|t]` [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html), which another necessary piece to perspective projection.

Comment: @beaker, sry and thanks for the response. I'm not sure how to verify the calibration camera matrix is correct. I have 10 images, and I managed to get a hold a camera matrix, and distortion coefficients. I'm not aware on how to get the rotation-translation matrix, nor intrinsic perspective projection

Comment: I don't have time to type out a full answer right now, but I wanted to get back to you in case this helps. I'll check back when I have a bit more time. At the top of the page from the link I gave you earlier there is an equation `s m' = A[R|t]M'`. `s` is the `w` in your equation. `m'` are the `image points`, `M'` the `object points`, `R` the `rvecs` and `t` the `tvecs`, all for a given view (one of your 10 images), used as inputs/outputs to `calibrateCamera`. If you multiply the object points by the corresponding matrices, you  should get the image points back.

Comment: @beaker, totally what I was looking for.

Comment: @beaker, that's an acceptable answer, feel free to submit it